# apache user not able to run sox command

Tags: php, apache, centos, shell-exec, sox

I have a test script which does following:

```
$a = shell_exec("sox /var/www/html/media/file-all.gsm -r 8000 -c 1  -e signed-integer /var/www/html/wav-files/file-all.wav");
```

- script runs as apache user
- source and destination both files and folders have 777 permission
- tried changing the group and ownership to apache user too

Still does not work.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: if I run the same script as `root` user, then it works.

Comment: Do you get any error message? If not, check if php.ini entries `error_reporting` and `display_errors` are set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is, that the `sox` command is not in the PATH used by apache user.

Specify the absolute path to `sox` in your `shell_exec()` call.